# How to read arduino data output using python via internet?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arduino, arduino-uno, ethernet

I have arduino project using uno and ethernet shield. I wan't to print arduino data output in python. I have done try this case using pySerial python and successful. 
Then now, I wan't to try my python can read arduino data output over internet, not serial python.

**Topology:
Arduino with eth. shield--->switch<---laptop**

*Note: the switch have internet connection from my router.

Can you help me, guys?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

The IP that you use here should be "localhost" since only the arduino needs the address of the computer and not the other way around. Your Python script is just listening for anyone to connect. Try this:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "localhost" # this computer
UDP_PORT = 3939 # the port that the arduino should connect to

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data
```

Comment: Thank you, it's helped me! but, after I run this python script, (I'm using cmd to run python) the cmd window do not print my arduino data output, is that mean the arduino is not connect with my python (laptop)?